# Why does ssh(d) seems to use OpenSSL heartbleed version?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, ssh, openssl, sshd

It is commonly known that the heartbleed bug exists in the OpenSSL versions 1.0.1 through 1.0.1f (inclusive).
So why are `ssh` and `sshd` compiled with OpenSSL 1.0.1, where the bug exists (12.04 -> OpenSSL 1.0.1, 14.04 -> OpenSSL 1.0.1f)?
The `libssl.so` is of course up-to-date, but if I run

```
ldd `which ssh`
# or
ldd `which sshd`
```

nothing links against the non corrupted versions of OpenSSL.
But if I run

```
sshd -V
# Under Ubuntu 12.04 it says:
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
# Under Ubuntu 14.04 it says:
OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

They explicitly saying, that they are compiled with a corrupted versions.
On https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh nothing is said about any update during the heartbeat bug release.

So how can I be sure, that `sshd` is not using an affected version of OpenSSL.
If if it does not use it, why do they explicitly saying, that they use an affected version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heartbleed only affects SSL/TLS connections, not every crypto function in the OpenSSL library, and sshd doesn't use SSL/TLS at all, so it's not affected by Heartbleed even if it's compiled using affected OpenSSL versions. See [this question and answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55300/do-i-need-to-worry-about-my-ssh-keys-if-my-system-was-vulnerable-to-heartbleed).